# Exception caught by widgets library error in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

[Source file with incoming error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwniO.png)

[Bottom Navigation Bar Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ueki4.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code. this answer will be downvoted and closed otherwise.
Also, please take a minute to read [ask]

Comment: No, you'll have to [edit] your question as _text_, not as an image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `BottomNavigationBar` there's an `items` property:

```dart
Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
    ]));
```

this property accepts a `List<BottomNavigationBarItem>`. Now, the length of this list should be at least 2.

For example:

```dart
Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: 'search'),
      ]),
    );
```

but your providing only one `BottomNavigationBarItem`, so make sure you have at least *one more* `BottomNavigationBarItem`

Comment: Thanks bro but thanks, it doesn't appear on the screen this time, what should i do, i just started flutter :)

Comment: @Eyyubi What do you mean?
You'll have to edit your question with the complete code.